# respond_with @model upon failing #destroy: append @model.errors[:base] to flash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm using the following code to destroy a model, together with the [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem and the `FlashResponder`:

```
def destroy
  @model.destroy
  respond_with @model
end
```

If the model fails to be destroyed, a `flash[:alert]` is displayed:

> Alert: Model could not be destroyed.

Usually there is more information about why the model could not be destroyed available in `@model.errors[:base]`. Is there a way to add this to the flash? I'd love to have displayed both the original message, together the base error.

I tried setting the flash like this:

```
flash[:alert] = "#{@wcag_element.errors[:base].to_sentence}." if @wcag_element.errors[:base].any?
respond_with @model
```

But this doesn't display the original message anymore.

The easiest solution at the moment seems to be to simply add the flash to `[:notice]` instead of `[:alert]`, but this doesn't really feel right:

```
flash[:notice] = ...
respond_with @wcag_element
```

Comment: Have you tried `flash[:alert] += @model.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`?

Answer (score 2):

`respond_with` also supports some options such as `:alert` and `:notice` as mentioned in their api here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/blob/02a18078aa9b6533c25fd28060f62f1452fd9157/lib/responders/flash_responder.rb#L64

```
respond_with(@user, :notice => "Hooray! Welcome!", :alert => "Woot! You failed.")
```

Therefore you can do it like this `respond_with @model, alert: 'Custom alert messsage'`

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the easiest solution:

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
private
  def respond_with *args
    options = args.extract_options!
    resource = args.first

    options[:alert] ||= resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence if resource.errors.any?

    super resource, options
  end
end
```

This way, I don't have to think about it anymore in each and every descendant controller.